# Maven Iterator/Invoker fails on Windows

Tags: maven, iterator

I have a Windows 10 System where I don't have administrative rights. However, most Maven builds are working on that machine. For some reason I run into a problem with the Iterator Plugin. Even the example from https://github.com/khmarbaise/iterator-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/it/invokerBasicTest/pom.xml fails with this error:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:<my home director>). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[INFO] [ERROR]
[INFO] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR]
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
[ERROR] ------ Maven call was NOT Ok. for iteration one ( return code: 1 )
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.567 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-08T10:04:40+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.soebes.maven.plugins:iterator-maven-plugin:0.5.0:invoker (default) on project invoker-basic-test: Maven call failed with return code 1 for iteration: one -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

So in other words, on that particular Windows system (I see that build working on Macs and other Windows machines), the invoker tries to find the pom.xml in my user home directory. And of course, I started the build in the right directory. The only significant thing what I have noticed on that Windows, the Environment variable MP_FORCE_USE_SANDBOX=1 is set.

-e and -X don't really help. Perhaps someone could help me out with some further hints in order to tackle down the problem.

Comment: The problem is: `no POM in this directory`... Apart from that I would ask: Why would you like to use iterator-maven-plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise This is part of a bigger build, where other maven builds are started from the iterator. The build itself is running without problems on multiple systems (Mac, Jenkins etc.). It only fails when I run it on that particular Windows system. And yes, of course there is no pom.xml in my home directory, the pom should be found in a subdirectory of my build. But why is maven looking for a pom.xml in my homedirectory instead of the subdirectory? I also tried to set the properties like working directory or pomFile etc... Always the same result.

Comment: Starting from iterator other parts is simply wrong and will run into trouble. I know that for two reasons. First I'm Maven committer and second I'm the author of the iterator-maven-plugin...First explain what kind of problem you are starting via iterator which sounds weirs...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for watching out for my problem, I am aware who you are... 
We are building a maven sub project with it's own pom.xml with different properties and deploy that subproject for different stages. I am also not able to change that architecture, especially it is working everywhere else besides that Windows 10 system. The Windows 10 is a virtual Windows which should be used for other developers. 
Do you have a hint how I could find out why Maven is looking in my home directory instead of the specified directory for the pom.xml? Are there other possibilities then -e or -X?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out what the problem was. It's not really a maven or Iterator Problem, more of a misconfigured Windows problem. However, in case someone comes over something like this, it may be worth to check.

In my case it was a Registry Key. In Windows there is a Registry Key `Autorun` under

```
\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

This Registry Key can control, in which directory a new cmd.exe will be started. In my case, there was `cd /d C:\<myHomeDirectory>`as a value. Which made the cmd.exe always start in my Home Directory. This caused my build to fail, because each iteration of the iterator supposably starts a new process in my Home Directory, which finally lets Maven search the desired pom.xml in my Home Directory.

For me the resolution for my problem is, change the Registry Key Autorun to the value `cd`.